# How can I retrieve the access token by calling to the URI inside vagrant box?

Tags: java, ubuntu, spring-boot, vagrant, netflix

I have gotten a problem when I tried to run the example at [here](https://github.com/callistaenterprise/blog-microservices). I got the source code, built and run it. That's okay on my local environment (windows 10 OS), but when I created a vagrantfile with Ubuntu image and tried to run it in Ubuntu environment, then I got an issue. Because that example used Spring Security for authentication the user so that I have to run the command below to get an access token

```
curl http://acme:acmesecret@localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/token \
  -d grant_type=password -d client_id=acme \
  -d username=user -d password=password -ks | jq .
```

That's fine if I use ssh and run it inside the vagrant box. But if I run it outside the box (log out ubuntu box, return to Windows OS and use Postman for submitting the request to get the access token at localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/token), I always cannot see the port **9999** inside the vagrant box. I have the config for port_forward in the vagrantfile as below

```
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8765, host: 8888 # API gateway port
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8761, host: 8761 # eureka port
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 7979, host: 7979 # hytrix port
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9999, host: 9999 # auth port, I try to portward 999 outside but could not sucess
```

Could anyone help me on that? I really get stuck at the moment :(

Comment: You need to change localhost to the IP of your VM